# SP2010: SPContext.Current.Web.ID Returns FirstUniqueAcestorWebID unexpected

Tags: 2010

I have a SP2010 server instance that is returning an unexpected result when calling SPContext.Current.Web.Id it returns the value in the AllWebs.FirstUniqueAncestorWebID.

We have 3 environments, 2 return the expected value, 1 does not return the expted value.

The 1 server that does not return the expected value is the one server that was a fresh install of 2010 and the ones that do display the expected value are upgrades from 2007. The upgrade failed on server 1 so we blew it away and reinstalled and then copied and restored the databases from the other server, so the databases are the same.

I have confirmed from powershell that the web.id returned is the expected id as located in the working server:

$web = SP-GetWeb -Identity "url" 
$web.id

I have added logging to the code and am logging the value returned from
 SPContext.Current.Web.ID

No matter what web site, in my site collection I am on, the same guid returns which is the FirstUniqueAncestorID.

I have been and am searching the web for this issue and have found it to be unique.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.
I am looking for an answer that does not require me to uninstall 2010, reinstall 2007 restore backups and then upgrade and restore the 2010 dbs and hope that fixes it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was to create a new Alternate Access Mapping. When that was done the proper site id was displaying.

Answer (score 0):

So after more research and review, it turns out the the site was missing an Alternate Access Mapping for localhost.

The site is a COOP failover site so the IIS bindings and other settings are not configured as normal and the site was browsing under the URL of  and was always returning the ID fo the parent site because Sharepoint could not match the URL in the browser so it returned the parent value. The reason behind the answer is my best guess but the issue was resolved by adding the AAM.

Thanks